# SSRS in Visual Studio doesn´t update directly after changes have been made

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am building a report with one "go to report" and in that new report I have one subreport. Now, when I´m sitting and working with the report and for instance changing the format for a cell the report doesn´t view the new changes directly. Sometimes it does. Sometimes I have to wait a while, sometimes I restart BIDS. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: I vaguely remember this happening to me... I think the way VS maintains subreport data when designing means the definitions can get stale; does a Rebuild Solution before previewing help? This should hopefully make sure everything is up to date and for a Report project/solution it should be quick to rebuild.

Comment: I don´t know why I don´t build my solution, I used to do it with development in regular C# project´s all the time.. It looks like it works great! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way VS maintains subreport data when designing means the definitions can get stale; does a **Rebuild Solution** before previewing help?

This should hopefully make sure everything is up to date and for a Report project/solution it should be quick to rebuild.